# Check if all module dependencies are met

Tags: magento2, module, cli, dependency

I recently disabled some modules and after an upgrade I feel that new dependencies got introduced (when disabling and re-enabling a custom module I got errors).

Is there a command to check if the current dependencies are all met?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a command to show the dependencies not sure if it is exactly what you need but it can help:

- `php bin/magento info:dependencies:show-modules` for modules dependencies
- `php bin/magento info:dependencies:show-modules-circular` for circular dependencies
- `php bin/magento info:dependencies:show-framework` for Magento framework dependencies

In Addition :

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-depen.html

Answer (score 0):

Try Using  `composer update --dry-run`